# Extract tuples that are changing values in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I possess two similar structure dataframes.
Take a dataframe A:

```
Name  | Col3 | Col4
------+------+------
  P    |  5   | 9            -1
  Q    |  0   | 1            -2
  R    |  2   | 7            -3
```

And another one B:

```
Name  | Col3 | Col4
------+------+------
  P    |  5   | 9            -1
  Q    |  0   | 6            -2
  R    |  4   | 7            -3
  S    |  5   | 10           -4
```

I have to extract the tuples that either are new or have changed values. Here tuple 1 from A and B are same. Tuple 2 and 3 have one changed value, and tuple 4 is new in dataframe B. I want to mark in another column if they have changed (putting 1 in the column) or not (putting 0 in the column).

So in the end I have value 0(if nothing changes) for tuple 1 and value 1(if something changes) for tuple 2, 3 and 4.

EDIT: The Name field can be considered as the key.

Comment: What should happen if there is a new row which is a copy of one that already existed? Should they both get a 1 or the first a 1 and the second a 0?

Comment: No that won't happen, no copies would exist

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the two data frames are related, there probably is a smarter, i.e. faster, way (tracking indices or such) but one way to do it is

```
B['is_in_A'] = B.apply(lambda x: int(~(A==x).all(axis=1).any()), axis=1)
```

This might be slow on large dataframes as for every row in `B` the lambda runs over `A`.

Comment: Do you have any idea to make it faster ?

Comment: Do you have information on how `A` and `B` are related? E.g. it could be that two lines match if and only if their index is preserved, then one does not have to check the entire `A`. Or maybe the ordering is preserved or something like that.

Comment: The name field can be considered as the index

Answer (score 1):

To find the set of rows in one Pandas DataFrame that don't exist in another DataFrame use the `isin` function and then aggregate over the row-index.

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({'name':['P','Q','R'], 'Col3':[5,0,2],'Col4':[9,1,7]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'name':['P','Q','R','S'], 'Col3':[5,0,4,5],'Col4':[9,6,7,10]})                                                                                                    

same_rows_idx = A.isin(B).all(1)
B['is_in_A'] = (~same_rows_idx).astype(int)
B['is_in_A'] =  B['is_in_A'].fillna(1)
```

Since this uses vectorized Pandas functions it should be fast on large tables.

Comment: This looks like the cleaner solution to me, one just has to replace NaNs by 1s.

Comment: Keep in mind that,  `isin` in dataframe level needs to match for both column value and index. If there is an instance that appends to the middle of  `B`, this approach can cause inaccuracy.

Comment: @zwjjoy is right. To be safe you might want to set the index first.

Comment: @groceryheist how do we do it if we set the Name column as the Index ?

Comment: the `set_index` function